# orchard userPart is cached?

Tags: c#, caching, orchardcms, infoset

I've been trying out Orchard and so far it seems to be awesome but there is one thing bugging me that i cant seem to figure out. Im implementing something that affects the UserPart object but when i update something directly into the database and i go thru debugging i found that the class still holds old values.
Ive tried rebuilding/ restarting the application pool but somehow this cache is somewhere else. I going thru documentation but didnt find anything usefull.

Is there someone who could tell me how to clear this cache when editing database data?

thanks

Comment: Probably not nearly enough details to be sure, but it's in general a super-bad idea to go against the database directly. Especially when most properties are implemented using the Infoset, so that editing the record will have no effect, as the Infoset data will win over the record data. Do yourself a favor and go through the part to modify data.

Comment: Infoset is new to me so thanks for dropping that keyword. Its highly possible that Infoset is related to my problem. I was editing the database data purly because of testing/developing purposes, I wouldnt do that on a production environment.
So what would be the best way to handle this? Like if im testing my app and want to see how stuff responds with different data, what would be the best way? And how could i reload this InfoSet for the UserPart?

Comment: If you really want to change things in the database, you'll have to update both the record and the relevant part of the XML in the corresponding Infoset record.

Comment: Thanks, I found this page to help me read about document storage and the answer: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/the-shift-how-orchard-painlessly-shifted-to-document-storage-and-how-it-ll-affect-you

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure if someone is magically searching for the same question i had: Read about the document storage of Orchard. Users are being stored in a "index" table and in a "Document/Record" table. So editing the index table(which i did) doesnt update the Record table which is being used. You can still do this by finding the right record in table: Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord, but as Bartrend suggested, dont edit the sql records.